# How make Visual Studio Code to stop showing typescript errors for node_modules folder?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I've installed some node packages on my project. However there is a few sub modules that contains some typescript errors.

I tried already to add the node_modules to the ignore configuration of tsconfig.json. but those errors still showing up.

How can I ignore them?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried already to add the node_modules to the ignore configuration of tsconfig.json. but those errors still showing up.

Even if you *exclude* them from tsconfig.json they get *included* if they are used by some code in your project.

## Fix

Fix the definitions or update your typescript or downgrade the definitions to al older version or delete them if they are not used. Alternatively use `--skipLibCheck` but this is will result in more issues down the line

Answer (score 1):

Those line numbers correspond to the two occurrences of `keyof` in the declaration file.  [You'll need to upgrade to TypeScript 2.1 or newer](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) for that to work.